# Get PC to send a video signal when monitor turned on AFTER PC has booted

Tags: display, graphics-card, external-display

We have a TV as a monitor in our conference room, but people always have to turn the TV on first, otherwise, the PC will not send a video signal.

Is there a way to get the pc to always send a signal or detect the monitor reliably?

Comment: Your assessment of the issue is likely incorrect.  The problem isnt the PC, its the TV.

Comment: Some information about the TV, computer and connection media would be useful.